# Run lambda parallely or better approach

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, architecture, amazon-sqs

i have a problem statement like this:

I have approx 40 servers in which i want to run a stored proc simultaneously, there is no dependency on each other.
The servers information is stored in an database.
To achieve this i am thinking to implement the following way:

- A lambda will get all the information about servers from DB. Lets say
  this is "lambda1".
- Put all this information into the SQS, there will    be a lambda
  attached to the SQS which will process the request. Lets    say
  "lambda2".

  I want to know if there will be as many instances of
  "lambda2", as number of messages in SQS.
  Or there can be better approach than this?

Comment: Why are you wanting to use AWS Lambda? If you wish to run commands on Amazon EC2 instances, you can use [AWS Systems Manager Run Command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/execute-remote-commands.html). It can run commands simultaneously on multiple instances (and even on your own computers!) and will collate the results from each instance.

Answer (score 0):

When you [create a trigger](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html) from SQS to Lambda you set the **Batch size** property with a value upto 10.

When 10 messages (or less if there's few in the queue) are received Lambda will be invoked and receive that batch of messages.

Comment: I have a question here if i set  batch size to 1 will there be 1 lambda for each msg in SQS.
If i set batch size to 5 there can be a possibility connection to fourth server takes time and 15 mint timeout happen for lambda

Comment: Hi, if you set to 1 it would be 1 Lambda per message. If theres any timeouts you can configure an SQS dead letter queue: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-dead-letter-queues.html

Comment: Can there be better design?

Comment: Hi, it really depends on your usecase but configuring an SQS queue with a batch size of 10 and a DLQ provides resilience. Remember that Lambdas are retried if the first consumer fails initially

Comment: The use is what is mentioned in the question, if you ca think of better design, you are most welcome.

Comment: @mokugo-devops *"if you set to 1 it would be 1 Lambda per message."* No, that isn't accurate.  There would be 1 message per Lambda, not 1 Lambda per message, unless there is a very small number of messages.  The Lambda/SQS integration starts up with only 5 internal listeners polling the queue and invoking the Lambdas synchronously with up to the number of messages in the batch size passed to the Lambda function invocation.

Comment: Hi @Michael-sqlbot thanks for noticing. I wrote these the wrong way round for the comment :(